# Raw H.264 stream output by MediaCodec not playble

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am creating raw H.264 stream output by MediaCodec. The problem is the output file is not playable in android default player (API 16). How can it be that Android can export file that is not playable in player, only in VLC on the PC. Maybe some thing wrong with my code? My video is 384x288.

```
public class AvcEncoder {

private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
private BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
private File f;

public AvcEncoder(int w, int h, String file_name) 
{ 
    f = new File(file_name + ".mp4");

    try {
        outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    } catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String key_mime = "video/avc"; //video/mp4v-es, video/3gpp, video/avc
    mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(key_mime);  
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(key_mime, w, h);

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, (w * h) << 3);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);

    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE,MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.MPEG4ProfileMain);
    mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mediaCodec.start();
}

public void close() {
    try {
        mediaCodec.stop();
        mediaCodec.release();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void offerEncoder(byte[] input) {
    try {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
        int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
            inputBuffer.clear();
            inputBuffer.put(input);
            mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
        }

        MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer outputBuffer = outputBuffers[outputBufferIndex];
            byte[] outData = new byte[bufferInfo.size];
            outputBuffer.get(outData);
            outputStream.write(outData, 0, outData.length);

            mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: For others coming across this problem: being able to play it in VLC is perfect and shows that the encoding is working. A h264 track is just "not boxed", so there is no way for a player to know how to play it. By the way, before API 18 it is very easy to mux it using Mp4Parser / IsoParser java library. It is especially good with AVC and replace MediaMuxer gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android `MediaPlayer` doesn't handle raw H.264 streams.

One difficulty with such streams is that the H.264 NAL units don't have timestamp information, so unless the video frames are at a known fixed frame rate the player wouldn't know when to present them.

You can either create your own player with `MediaCodec` (see e.g. "Play video (TextureView)" in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika)), or convert the raw stream to a .mp4 file.  The latter requires `MediaMuxer`, available in API 18, or the use of a 3rd-party library like ffmpeg.

Comment: What is known fixed frame rate?

Comment: The video has a known fixed frame rate if the timing between frames is known to the player and doesn't change, e.g. you happen to know that it's 30fps video.  If you play the "gen-eight-rects" video in Grafika, you can see the animation speed up... but if you select the "play at 60fps" checkbox there's no variation.  This is because the presentation time stamps are used to control playback speed, but when you check the "60fps" box they're ignored.  The Android 4.4 `screenrecord` tool uses this approach to avoid having to encode frames when nothing is changing on screen.